# Please how to ssh2 module with electron and webpack

Tags: process, electron, sftp

I try to create a sftp client with ssh2 module , angular-electron from https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron
 when in try to build my electron app : the app is build correctly but when in try to package app with **npm run electron:local** or **npm run electron:windows**

I get error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ssh2/lib/agent.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\BITBUCKET\SERVER\ElectronSFTPClient\node_modules\ssh2\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\BITBUCKET\SERVER\ElectronSFTPClient\node_modules\ssh2\lib'
```

ssh2/lib/client.js ther is : var dnsLookup = require('dns').lookup;
   ssh2/lib/agent.js: var cp = require('child_process');

Electron use webpack and i 've already add :

**"target": eletron-render** 
and
**"externals": {
    fs: 'fs',
    child_process: 'child_process'
  }**

Please help